# how to select from case name in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, select, view, case, greatest-n-per-group

I use postgres v14,
I create a postgres view it contain 5 time columns.

Every user id have a date in side one column

it mean every userid have more than 4 rows

i want to get one row have greatest row

my cols is (id,created_at, newstage_created_at ,newstage_updated_at,newdata_created_at)
look like

| id | created_at | newstage_created_at | newstage_updated_at | newdata_created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-11-23 11:28:05 | 2020-11-23 11:28:05 | 2020-11-23 11:28:05 | null |
| 1 | 2020-11-23 11:28:05 | 2020-11-23 11:28:05 | 2020-11-24 08:13:48 | 2020-11-25 08:13:48 |
| 1 | 2020-11-23 11:28:05 | 2020-10-11 05:55:36 | 2021-01-11 05:55:36 | 2020-10-11 05:55:36 |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | null |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2020-10-12 09:55:31 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 |
| 2 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2020-10-12 09:55:31 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 | 2022-02-09 18:41:42 |

here i need to get the row have greatest column and greatest row

i did this sql

```
case greatest(created_at, newstage_created_at ,newstage_updated_at,newdata_created_at)
when created_at then 'created_at'
when newstage_created_at then 'newstage_created_at'
when newstage_updated_at then 'newstage_updated_at'
when newdata_created_at then 'newdata_created_at'
else null
end greatestcolumn
FROM people_count_view 
WHERE 
annonce_id='1'
and 
(id,greatestcolumn) in (select id,greatestcolumn from people_count_view)
order by id
```

of course `greatestcolumn` is not column name, it was bad attemp

Comment: Read your posting twice. Still don't know what the question is. Please clarify. And always declare your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I understand your task correct, but you can take this code and modify (in generally it seems like what you want to get).

```
with t as (
select id,
       max(created_at)::timestamp as max_created_at,
       max(newstage_created_at) as max_newstage_created_at,
       max(newstage_updated_at) as max_newstage_updated_at,
       max(newdata_created_at) as max_newdata_created_at
from test.people_count_view
GROUP BY id
order by id)
select
    id,
    greatest(max_created_at,
        max_newstage_created_at,
        max_newstage_updated_at,
        max_newdata_created_at) as greatestcolumn,
    case greatest(max_created_at,
        max_newstage_created_at,
        max_newstage_updated_at,
        max_newdata_created_at)
        when max_created_at then 'max_created_at'
        when max_newstage_created_at then 'max_newstage_created_at'
        when max_newstage_updated_at then 'max_newstage_updated_at'
        when max_newdata_created_at then 'max_newdata_created_at'
        end as greatestcolumn_name
    from t;
```

[output result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa9Um.png)

Regarding your code - just remember not to use aliases (greatestcolumn) in WHERE conditions. In my case, I wrapped the query in a CTE to use it as column name. Other way - in WHERE block you need to use the same condition that you use in CASE with this alias